# Documentation of functions (author, deprecated, etc.)

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

Most web apps have a special way to describe their functions.
Like this:

```
/**
 * Represents a template function.
 *
 * Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead.
 *
 * @author Arnaud Le Blanc <arnaud.lb@gmail.com>
 * @deprecated since 1.12 (to be removed in 2.0)
 */
```

Do you know how this type of documentation is called? I am looking for the convention to use it too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Javadoc? Link here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html

Comment: Please do not give just a link in the answer. Explain the most important parts in your answer.